# How to feedback joint positions to MoveIt?

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with a robot we built (with three joints), and control it through ROS such that everything goes well.
However I have a doubt about how to properly feedback the joint states to moveit.

It is, currently I run `demo.launch` file and I created a node which subscribes to `/joint_states` topic and moves every motor to its own goal position (joint angle). Nevertheless, although I defined velocity in SRDF according with motors datasheets, I noted that robot in Rviz moves faster than real robot, such that trajectories (real and generated) mismatch. In order to avoid it, I just included a wait/sleep function to wait until every motor reaches its target before continuing to next position.

So, how could I feedback the current joint position directly to moveit and then to avoid the wait/sleep function?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310295/how-to-feedback-joint-positions-to-moveit?/) by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2018-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using `joint_states` for control is not the way things are meant to be done. As the name of the message implies, [JointState](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html) messages are used to report on *current state*, not command a desired one.

You'll want to write a [FollowJointTrajectory](http://docs.ros.org/api/control_msgs/html/action/FollowJointTrajectory.html) action server for your arm or re-use one, such as `ros_control`'s `joint_trajectory_controller`. Re-use would be preferred if possible.

A [JointTrajectory](http://docs.ros.org/api/trajectory_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectory.html) contains timestamps, positions, velocity and acceleration that, if properly used, should result in synchronised motion of all joints.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3